# Trigger an action after the iterating through an observable

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, rxjs, rxjs5

I am quite new to rxjs . I just want to trigger an redux action after an observables stop emitting data.

```js
const removeUsersEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$
    .ofType(REMOVE_USERS)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      Rx.Observable.from(action.payload).mergeMap(user => {
        return Rx.Observable.authorizedAjax({
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/form-data' },
          method: 'DELETE',
          url: `${consoleBaseUrl}/api/v1/users/${user}`,
          body: {}
        })
          .mergeMap(() =>
            Rx.Observable.of(
              setUserDeleteCount(store.getState().components.userListComponentData.deletedUserCount + 1),
              getUserCount()
            )
          )
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            return Rx.Observable.of(
              setUserDeleteExceptionCount(
                store.getState().components.userListComponentData.deleteUserExceptionCount + 1
              ),
              getUserCount()
            )
          })
      }).map(()=>{return setDeleteOperationStatus(true)})
    )
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
      return Rx.Observable.empty()
    })
```

In this example, I am trying to trigger `setDeleteOperationStatus` at the end. `action.payload` is nothing but list of userids to be deleted. I am looping through ids and deleting them one by one. At the end of loop I just want to perform some action. I tried using `.map` , `mergemap` but it didn't work.

Comment: It didn't work how? Is the problem that `setDeleteOperationStatus` is called on every emission from the source Observable and not only at the end?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like they are cold observables (they have an end)
if this is true then you can use the "onCompleted" method of ".subscribe()"

.subscribe(onNext(), onError(), onCompleted())

if it is a hot observable (for example something like an event emitter)
you'd have to use a buffer like bufferCount() or bufferTime() based on the information you have.

sorry it's hard to explain cold/hot observables in a nutshell